# I don't understand why we put the "&" in the scanf with ageAmis while ageAmis is a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

That's the code: I don't understand why we put the "&" in the scanf with ageAmis while ageAmis is a pointer? 
NB "This code works"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int nombreDAmis = 0, i = 0;
int* ageAmis = NULL; // Ce pointeur va servir de tableau après l'appel du malloc

// On demande le nombre d'amis à l'utilisateur
printf("Combien d'amis avez-vous ? ");
scanf("%d", &nombreDAmis);


    ageAmis = malloc(nombreDAmis * sizeof(int)); // On alloue de la mémoire pour le tableau


    // On demande l'âge des amis un à un
    for (i = 0 ; i < nombreDAmis ; i++)
    {
        printf("Quel age a l'ami numero %d ? ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &ageAmis[i]); //why the "&"
    }

    // On affiche les âges stockés un à un
    printf("\n\nVos amis ont les ages suivants :\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < nombreDAmis ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ans\n", ageAmis[i]);
    }

    // On libère la mémoire allouée avec malloc, on n'en a plus besoin
    free(ageAmis);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Because `ageAmis[i]` is a value (as passed to `printf`), and `&ageAmis[i]` is its location, so that it can be altered by `scanf`.

Comment: _ageAmis_ is a pointer but _ageAmis[i]_ is not apointer but an _int_, so you have to give the address (&) for _ageAmis[i]_ exactly like you did for _nombreDAmis_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that `ageAmis` is a pointer. However, that's not what you pass to `scanf()`.

`ageAmis[i]` has type `int` because you are dereferencing `i` location from `ageAmis` base address. It's equivalent to `*(ageAmis + i)`. That's you can't pass `ageAmis[i]` to `scanf` as it expects an argument of type `int*` for the format `%d`. So `&` is required here.

You could alternatively just pass `ageAmis + i` as well:

```
    scanf("%d", ageAmis + i);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
    scanf("%d", &ageAmis[i]);
```

Note that:

```
*(ageAmis + i) == *(i + ageAmis) == ageAmis[i]
```

Comment: And, perhaps better left for code obfuscation, `== i[ageAmis]`